# Transition between UIAlertControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uialertcontroller

What I need to do is present an alert controller with a progressBar. Once the download is complete, I need to transition to a secondary alert controller with a Success! message and an "Ok" button for the user to just exit this setup. I have built the alerts separately and they are working well on their own (well the progress bar is kinda working...) but with this code:

*I expect that when the progressBar hits 100% the first alert controller will be dismissed and the next alert will show up, but nothing is happenning* This is my code:

```
-(void)settingUpToolsProgressPopUp {
 UIAlertController* progressAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Setting up tools ..." message:@"This could take a few minutes. Make sure to keep your tools near your mobile device." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
 [self presentViewController:progressAlert animated:YES completion:^{
 //Progress bar setup
 UIProgressView *progressView;
 progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8.0, 98.0, progressAlert.view.frame.size.width - 16, 100.0)];

 [[progressView layer]setCornerRadius:50];
 progressView.trackTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 progressView.progressTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
      progressNumerator = 1.0;
      progressDenominator = 1.0;
      currentProgress = (float)(progressNumerator/progressDenominator);
      [progressView setProgress: currentProgress animated:YES];
 [progressAlert.view addSubview:progressView];

  if(currentProgress > 1.0){
      [self settingUpToolsProgressPopUp];
 } else if(currentProgress == 1.0){
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
      [self successAlertPopUp];
 }

 }];


 }
```

p.s. I know that the values are hardcoded right now... but regardless of any values I use the transition doesn't happen. I don't have access to the updating values yet, so I can't use other values right now... but I would expect that if I am using 100% value, then the transition would happen anyway?

Can anyone point me int he right direction? Why isn't this code working for transitioning between these controllers?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried calling `successAlertPopUp` inside `dismissViewControllerAnimated`'s completion handler?

Comment: I think you have to make custom alert which is inherits to `UIAlertController`.

Comment: @shahnilay86 hi Thanks so much for your answer! I thought that is what i was doing building the progressAlert. Or am I doing it wrong? if you notice int he code I built it like this `UIAlertController* progressAlert = [UIAlertController alloc]init` ? Thanks again so much

Comment: @MohammadrezaFarahani THANK YOU SO MUCH!! This is exactly what worked!! I will update in the main question so that anyone who finds this question in the future can see it in there easily.

Comment: @valeriana You're welcome :] I'll post that as an answer then.

Comment: @MohammadrezaFarahani awesome! I'll accept it as soon as it shows up on my end. Thanks again!  :)

Comment: @valeriana You're most welcome :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `successAlertPopUp` method inside `dismissViewControllerAnimated`'s completion handler:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self successAlertPopUp];
}];
```